# How to insert MultiPartFile data in Junit Param

Tags: spring, junit

I've started project test with Junit.

I was trying to test one method using Junit param than I got error message and red line on eclipse.

this is my red line

[red box is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qolxu.png)

I just wonder how can I use this MockMultipartFile in Junit param

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to stackoverflow, can you please add some details to your question and share your code as a text (not an image), you can find the site's guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I didn't know. 
The image file dosen't show here..
please, just Click "red box is my problem" to see my image file
I'm so sorry!